# Fixing row height while writing vertical

Tags: tables

I am writing vertical in a row and as text is long the row is getting insane height. following is my code and result.

```
\begin{table}[H]
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1.5cm}|}
 \hline
 & \begin{turn}{90} Starting points \end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90} II. Control of production, retail sale and distribution of alcoholic beverages \end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}III. Age limits and personal control \end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90} IV. Control of drunk driving \end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90} V. Control of advertising, marketing and sponsorship of alcoholic beverages \end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90} VI. Public Policy \end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90} VII. Alcohol taxation and prices \end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90} Total \end{turn} \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Max points} & \textbf{0} & \textbf{40} & \textbf{24} & \textbf{24} & \textbf{24} & \textbf{8} & \textbf{40} & \textbf{160}\\
 \hline
 The Nordic monopoly profile & - & 24.3 (61.3\%) & 19.5 (81\%) & 14.5 (60\%)& 14.5(60\%) & 6.5 (81\%) & 40 (100\%) & 119.3 (75\%)\\
 \hline
 The eastern European profile & - & 12.8 (32\%) & 17.1 (71\%) & 11.4 (47\%)& 9.2(38\%) & 5.5 (69\%) & 16.9 (42\%) & 73 (46\%)\\
 \hline 
 The west/central European profile & - & 9.4 (24\%) & 11 (46\%) & 8.2 (34\%)& 3.6 (15\%) & 6.4 (80\%) & 22.4 (56\%) & 61 (38\%)\\
 \hline 
 The southern European profile & - & 11.1 (28\%) & 10 (42\%) & 8.7 (36\%)& 4.5(19\%) & 6.7 (83\%) & 12.3 (31\%) & 53.3 (33\%)\\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: You could put the contents inside a `\parbox{}{}` say `\begin{turn}{90}\parbox{10pc}{\raggedright Starting points}\end{turn}`.

Comment: my neck hurts… Do you really want to have vertical text along with horizontal text?